# Searching for id with most matches in separate keyword table

Tags: php, mysql, search, query-optimization

Imagine you have two tables

```
 table: name            table: keyword
 id   name              nameId   keyword
 1    dude1             1        blue
 2    dude2             1        tall
                        2        blue
                        2        short
```

My objective is that if you search for blue and tall the result would be:

```
name   matches
dude1  2
dude2  1
```

I am also using PHP but I would like to do as much as I can with only MySQL.
Any ideas? Pointing me in the right direction would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join both columns using `INNER JOIN` (*that's it if you want only records that has atleast a match on the other table otherwise use `LEFT JOIN`*) and link them with `name.id = keyword.nameid`. Use aggregate function `COUNT` and group them by their name.

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(b.nameID)
FROM name a INNER JOIN keyword b
        on a.id = b.nameID
WHERE b.keyword = 'tall' or
      b.keyword = 'blue'
GROUP BY a.name
```

or

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(b.nameID)
FROM name a INNER JOIN keyword b
        on a.id = b.nameID
WHERE b.keyword IN ('tall','blue') 
GROUP BY a.name
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd9b4/7)

Comment: By grouping by the name you are assuming it is unique which in general it is not or there would not be the need for an id.

Comment: @Clodoaldo if you dont group them, you will only have 1 record return after execution

Comment: @Clodoaldo [see this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd9b4/9) if you don't group them

Comment: Look at [what happens](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfc76/4) when the name is not unique

Comment: @Clodoaldo well, fair enough. the op didn't say anything about it.

Comment: Wouldn't grouping by b.nameID be better if it has no other side effects apart from having to include b.nameID as a field in SELECT fieldlist?

Answer (score 0):

```
select n.name, `matches`
from
    name n
    inner join (
        select id, count(*) as `matches`
        from
            name n
            inner join
            keyword k on n.id = k.nameId
        where keyword in ('blue', 'tall')
        group by id
    ) s on s.id = n.id
order by name
```